# Will this HTTP Web API call cause deadlock?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, optimization, async-await, deadlock

I would like to know your feedback to optimize the code. Will this cause deadlock or performance problems? This is calling a Web API method and using .Net 4.7

Some posts suggest to use async and await when using GetAsync to avoid deadlocks. Should HttpRequestException handling, TaskCanceledException and CancelPendingRequests be used?

```
public ItemDTO GetItem(int itemId)
 {
    var result = new ItemDTO();
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
        var response = client.GetAsync(String.Format(apiUrl + "store/GetItemDetails/{0}", itemId)).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ItemDTO>().Result;
        else
            throw new Exception(response.StatusCode + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Store.ManageException.HandleException(ex);
        throw new GetItemsException(ex.Message);
    }
    return result;
 }
```

**UPDATE:**
Sometimes the IIS server hangs. Here is the DebugDiag2 Analysis - CrashHangAnalysis report. Is this causing deadlock?

```
Thread ID   Total CPU Time  Entry Point for Thread
2   00:00:00.031    ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
0   00:00:00.030    w3wp+2e50
1   00:00:00.000    nativerd!DllGetClassObject+24680
3   00:00:00.000    ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
4   00:00:00.000    w3tp!THREAD_POOL::CreateThreadPool+350

4 Threads (40% of all threads) have this same call stack.
Note: Grouping of identical threads can be disabled in the 'Preferences' tab of the Analysis Options
Thread 2 - System ID 4704
Entry point   ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
Create time   9/20/2021 1:00:34 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.031


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Thread 3 - System ID 2576
Entry point   ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
Create time   9/20/2021 1:00:34 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.000


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Thread 8 - System ID 2112
Entry point   ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
Create time   9/20/2021 1:00:34 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.000


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Thread 9 - System ID 5832
Entry point   ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+2200
Create time   9/20/2021 1:01:04 PM
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 00:00:00.000
Time spent in kernel mode     0 Days 00:00:00.000


This thread is not fully resolved and may or may not be a problem. Further analysis of these threads may be required.
Instruction Address       Source
[0x7ffadb029444]    ntdll!NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory+14    
[0x7ffadaf9eb4e]    ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockExclusive+296e     
[0x7ffada7184d4]    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+14   
[0x7ffadafd1781]    ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+21
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are the issues you will have with the above code:

- The use of `GetAsync` is least of your problems.
  You seem to be calling the `GetItems` action from within the action (`store/GetItem/{0}`). It is becoming a recursive call. But without a termination condition and over Http! Serious performance problem and stack overflow type issue will occur in your code for this.
- Try to avoid throwing exceptions as much as possible. Handle your business logic without exception if possible.
- I don't see that any Http status code 500 (exception occurred) is handled when you are calling the `GetItems` action.
- Use `GetAsync` but use `await` instead of `.Result`

Can you describe what you intend to do here? Perhaps create a private function and call it recursively from the action. Then When you have the final result then only return it from the action.

Comment: Thanks @Rahatur. It doesn't call recursively. Sorry about the typo. It should be GetItem() and returns single Item details. There are some other methods which returns List of Items. Should I be using GetAsync() in this case?

Comment: Using `.Result` on async functions is very bad and a major problem. See [David Fowler's async guidance post](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#avoid-using-taskresult-and-taskwait) for more information. 2) Throwing exceptions is not something that should be avoided. Not throwing them hides the root cause of problems and also hides the *actual* problem in the code.

Comment: @nbokmans The post is very helpful. thank you.

Comment: @nbokmans I did not suggest consume an exception. My suggestion is to handle business logic without in a form of exception.

Comment: @user1979284 I have updated my answer. However calling `store/GetItem/{0}` from within the `GetItem` action seems to be recursive to me! Or do you have two actions with the same name?

Comment: @Rahatur, public ItemDTO GetItem(int itemId) method is in a wrapper class. And String.Format(apiUrl + "store/GetItem/{0}" calls an API method. So store/GetItem/{0} doesnt call GetItem(). Thanks